# How to compile multiple themes using a common SCSS file?

Tags: css, sass

I have a file structure as below in my project.

```
theme1
   --def.scss
theme2
   --def.scss
theme3
   --def.scss
control.scss
```

I would like to compile each theme def.scss with control.scss and get each theme css ouptput. I have tried the below way to compile.

**def.scss:**

```
$hcolor: #000000;
$bcolor: #cccccc;
```

**control.scss:**

```
@import 'theme1/def.scss';
.theme-color{
   color: $hcolor;
   background-color: $bcolor;
}
```

But it will compile only one theme. Is there any built in functionality available in SASS to compile a single file with multiple definition file?

Comment: Do your themes have different variables/classes, or do they all have the same `$hcolor` variable and classes? If they have different variables (or classes), you can just use [partials](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project).

Comment: Have you given any thought at all as to how one would go about this?  Have you *tried* anything?

Comment: @litel: All def.scss have same variables but different values

Comment: @cimmanon: currently i am manually edit the import path against all themes. Also I tried to set a dynamic variable in the import path like  "@import '#{$theme}/def.scss", but i dont think it is a best way to import multiple files.

Comment: @cimmanon: Is it "--load-path" option available in node-sass?